# Boy surface parameterization confusion

Tags: geometry, notation, surfaces

I'm looking at equations 10, 11 and 12 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BoySurface.html). What do the letters I and R represent in these equations?

Comment: Real and imaginary parts (of a complex number). Note that $z$ is a complex number lying in the unit disk in the complex plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notation is read as, I=Imaginary and R=Real.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the set of complex numbers.

Any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ can be represented as

$$z=x+iy$$

where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

We define $\mathcal{Im}(z)$ or just $\mathcal{I}(z)$ to be the imaginary part of $z$, thus

$$\mathcal{Im}(z)=\mathcal{I}(z)=y$$

And we define $\mathcal{Re}(z)$ or just $\mathcal{R}(z)$ to be the imaginary part of $z$, thus

$$\mathcal{Re}(z)=\mathcal{R}(z)=x$$